# How do I move something I made in Microsoft Blend into Visual Basic?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, blend

I need to submit a project tomorrow, and the topic is WPF using XAML. We are using VB by the way. Now I am still a beginner at programming, so I needed help. I've got a ton of WPF and blend tutorials open in tabs in my browser, but I have no idea where to start, and no idea for a project. I asked my tutor and he said he'll be checking our understanding of XAML, and creating an object using XAML as well as the other way round.

I stumbled onto some tutorials of media players main in WPF, and I decided to go with it. But because I have never used blend or WPF along with XAML before, I don't know what to do, if say I make a button in blend with effects, so that I may add coding behind it in VB. Please help me out. I've got like 15 hours before I have to submit.

Comment: Eep, I feel bad for you, but this isn't a real programming question :(

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need [Microsoft VB.Net Express 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/Download-2010.aspx)

at least. I'm not honestly sure if it supports WPF but it is free.

I'd look it up and start drinking coffee. If it does I guess copying your xaml into a new project is the place to start.

Comment: Microsoft Blend and VB use the same project files, so you should be able to open it directly in VB to add your code.